# xpath expression where the index of top node is unknown

Tags: xslt, xpath

In the below XML, we want the value of the second occurence of element c, under the whole xml, which is 'Result'. What xpath expression, can be used to get this?
Note that i do not know the index of 'a' element, in my code. If I know the index of a, the xpath is easy(/root/a[4]/b/c).

However, all we know is the second occurence of element c under the whole document. The document structure is the same, ie, there are two cases. One with no values for element a. The second one, element b and c, can come under element a.

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>junkdata</c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>Result</c>
    </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the path expression `descendant::c[2]`.

Comment: This expression made it simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

**Or use the even shorter**:

```
(//c)[2]
```